# how to split string on word and punctuation

Tags: python, split

I am relatively new to Python, is there a way I can split the string `"James kicked Bob's ball, laughed and ran away."` into the following, so I have the words and punctuation in list items `["James", "kicked", "Bob's", "ball", ",", "laughed", "and", "ran", "away", "."]`. is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Is there any space between `ball` and `,` ?

Comment: you want "," and "." as separate words, but not single quote(')? am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 import re
 str = "James kicked Bob's ball, laughed and ran away."

 x = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", str)
 print(x)
```

Output:

```
['James', 'kicked', "Bob's", 'ball', ',', 'laughed', 'and', 'ran', 'away', '.']
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to tokenize a sentence.
Some tokenizer already exists and perform well.

For example, you can use [spacy](https://spacy.io/).
Once install, you will need to download the model of your language:

```
python -m spacy download en
```

Then you will be able to use it in your script:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
tokens = list(nlp("James kicked Bob's ball, laughed and ran away."))
```

Output:

```
['James', 'kicked', 'Bob', "'s", 'ball', ',', 'laughed', 'and', 'ran', 'away', '.']
```

By using a tokenizer, it will take care of some corner cases. For example, the sentence `'I tried but it failed...'` will be tokenized as `['I', 'tried', 'but', 'it', 'failed', '...']`. Here the dots at the end are grouped together as only one token. In the same way, `"don't"` is tokenize as `['do', "n't"]` instead of the basic `['don', "'t"]`